# Auto-completion of \lvert in AucTex

Tags: auctex, electric-pair-mode

I wish to "electrically" insert `\rvert` or `\Bigr\rvert` when typing `\lvert` or `\Bigl\lvert` in AucTeX.

Comment: What does that mean? Just what do you want to know how to do?

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to automatically insert \rvert when I type \lvert (like with parenthesis for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Please consult the [`AucTeX` user manual](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/auctex/Top).

#### Use the search box in the right top corner of webpage to search for things of interest to you.

***You are looking for `C-c RET` `TeX-insert-macro`***

I had to do this

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

`lvert` comes from `amsmath`, and I believe you need to have `\usepackage{amsmath}` somewhere in your buffer.

***`TeX-insert-macro`***

[image: TeX-insert-macro]

`TeX-insert-macro` is an interactive byte-compiled Lisp function in `tex.el`.

```lisp
(`TeX-insert-macro` `SYMBOL`)
```

Insert TeX macro `SYMBOL` with completion.

AUCTeX knows of some macros and may query for extra arguments, depending on the value of `TeX-insert-macro-default-style` and whether `TeX-insert-macro` is called with `C`-u.

---

**[(AucTex) Quotes](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/auctex/Quotes#command-tex-insert-braces)**

or

```lisp
(info "(auctex) Quotes")
```

**When writing complex math formulas in LaTeX documents, you sometimes need to adjust the size of braces with pairs of macros like `\left`-`\right`, `\bigl`-`\bigr` and so on.  You can avoid unbalanced pairs with the help of `TeX-insert-macro`, bound to `C-c C-m` or `C-c <RET>` (note Completion::).  If you insert left size adjusting macros such as `\left`, `\bigl` etc. with `TeX-insert-macro`, it asks for left brace to use and supplies automatically right size adjusting macros such as `\right`, `\bigr` etc. and corresponding right brace in addtion to the intended left macro and left brace.**

**The completion by `TeX-insert-macro` also applies when entering macros such as `\langle`, `\lfloor` and `\lceil`, which produce the left part of the paired braces.  For example, inserting `\lfloor` by `C-c C-m` is immediately followed by the insertion of `\rfloor`.  In addition, if the point was located just after `\left` or its friends, the corresponding `\right` etc. will be inserted in front of `\rfloor`.  In both cases, active region is honored.**

**As a side effect, when `LaTeX-math-mode` (note Mathematics::) is on, just typing  `(` inserts not only `\langle`, but also `\rangle`.**

If you do not like such auto completion at all, it can be disabled by a user option.

-- **User Option: `TeX-arg-right-insert-p`** If this option is turned off, the automatic supply of the right macros and braces is suppressed.

---

**[(AucTeX) Completion](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/auctex/Completion#command-tex-insert-macro)**

or

```lisp
(info "(auctex) Completion")
```

A more direct way to insert a macro is with `TeX-insert-macro`, bound to `C-c C-m` which is equivalent to  `C-c <RET>`.  It has the advantage over completion that it knows about the argument of most standard LaTeX macros, and will prompt for them.  It also knows about the type of the arguments, so it will for example give completion for the argument to `\include`.  Some examples are listed below.

-- **Command: TeX-insert-macro (`C-c C-m` or `C-c <RET>`)** Prompt (with completion) for the name of a TeX macro, and if AUCTeX knows the macro, prompt for each argument.

As a default selection, AUCTeX will suggest the macro last inserted or, as the first choice the value of the variable `TeX-default-macro`.

-- **User Option: `TeX-default-macro`** Default macro to insert when invoking `TeX-insert-macro` first time.

-- **User Option: `TeX-insert-macro-default-style`** Specifies whether `TeX-insert-macro` will ask for all optional arguments.

If set to the symbol `show-optional-args`, `TeX-insert-macro` asks for optional arguments of TeX marcos, unless the previous optional argument has been rejected.  If set to `show-all-optional-args`, `TeX-insert-macro` asks for all optional arguments.  `mandatory-args-only`, `TeX-insert-macro` asks only for mandatory arguments.  When `TeX-insert-macro` is called with prefix argument (`C-u`), it`s the other way round.

Note that for some macros, there are special mechanisms, e.g.  `TeX-arg-cite-note-p` and `LaTeX-includegraphics-options-alist`.

A faster alternative is to enable the option `TeX-electric-escape`.

---